# Is this map $f:\prod_{k\geq 1} \{0,1,2,3\}\rightarrow \prod_{k\geq 1} \{0,1\}$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

> Let me define $f:\prod_{k\geq 1} \{0,1,2,3\}\rightarrow \prod_{k\geq 1} \{0,1\}$ where I map the entries of a sequence $x\in \prod_{k\geq 1} \{0,1,2,3\}$ to the following points:  $$0,1\mapsto 0,~~2,3\mapsto 1$$ Then I want to show if the map is continuous.

I know that on $\prod_{k\geq 1} \{0,1,2,3\}$ we have the metric $d_1(x,y)=\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{|x_k-y_k|}{4^k}$ and on $\prod_{k\geq 1} \{0,1\}$ we have the metric $d_2(x,y)=\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{|x_k-y_k|}{2^k}$. But now if I assume that $d_1(x,y)<\epsilon$ for an arbitrary $\epsilon >0$ then how can I bound $d_2(f(x),f(y))$? I mean $$d_2(f(x),f(y))=\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{|f(x)_k-f(y)_k|}{2^k}$$ but I don't see how to continue. Is this even possible?

Comment: $\vert f(x)_k-f(y)_k\vert\leq \vert x_k-y_k\vert$

Comment: @Alex but how do I get rid of $\frac{..}{4^k}$ respectively how can I use this as an upper bound

Comment: At first sight I thought thats just a constant so no problem; but I dont think so anymore. Here is what I would try: characterize open balls in both spaces. They should be something like this: The $\epsilon$-ball around $x$ consists of all sequences which are equal to $x$ in the first $\sigma(\epsilon)$ components. I think $\sigma(2^{-k})=k$ or something like this. Then show that the preimage of such an open ball along $f$ is again an open ball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon >0$. Choose $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1/2^m < \varepsilon$. Now, choose $\delta = 1/4^m$. If $d_1(x,y)< \delta$ then
$x_k=y_k$ for each $k \in \{1,\dots,m\}$ (since $x_k \not= y_k$ implies $|x_k-y_k| \ge 1$). Hence $f(x)_k=f(y)_k$ for each $k \in \{1,\dots,m\}$. Thus
$$
d_2(f(x),f(y)) \le \sum_{k=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}= \frac{1}{2^m} < \varepsilon.
$$
So, $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Why do you know that if $d_1(x,y)<\delta$ then $x_k=y_k$ for all $1\leq k\leq m$?

Comment: if $x_k\not= y_k$ then $|x_k-y_k| \ge 1$, hence $d_1(x,y) \ge |x_k-y_k|/4^k \ge 1/4^k$. If $d_1(x,y) < 1/4^m$ the first $m$ summands are $0$, since otherwise $1/4^k < 1/4^m$ for some $k \le m$, which is not possible..

Comment: Thank's a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Establish the following claim:

**Claim 1:** *Let $\epsilon$ be any positive number. If the inequality $d_1(x,y) < \epsilon$ is satisfied, then so is the inequality $d_2(f(x)-f(y))$ $\le$ $\sqrt{\epsilon}$.*

To establish Claim 1: If the inequality $d_1(x,y) < \epsilon$ is satisfied, then $x$ and $y$ must agree to at least the $\log_4 \Big(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\Big)$-th digit. Thus $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ must also agree to at least the $\log_4\Big(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\Big)$-th digit. So $d_2(f(x)-f(y))$ cannot be  any larger than $2^{-\log_4\Big(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\Big)}$ $=\sqrt{\epsilon}$.